# Why calling a service within another service is causing unexpected calling behaviour?

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

Suppose, I call one service returning observable and if it doesn't throw any error then should call another service which also returns `observable`.

What I have done is that I have called both separately such as one after the other but when I debug the back end it is simultaneously jumping between the 2 called apis and behaves abnormally.

```
this.taskServices.addService().subscribe((s) => {
     if(s) {
       this.taskServices.clean().subscribe(s=> {
     console.write('done')
  });
     }
});
```

The code might not be correct syntax wise since I typed using a cell phone but gives the idea.

Comment: Nesting subscriptions is a bad idea. Use a switchMap operator to switch from the first to the second observable. Also on a phone so typing an answer is not handy 

Comment: Haha thanks Mike , i will check

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment provide by @MikeOne, subscribing inside another subscribe is a bad practice, is call, **callback hell**; for that, you must use High RxJs order operators such as `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap` and `exhaustMap`, so depending on what you need, you will need to use one of them.

For instance, you could use `mergeMap` like this:

```js
this.taskServices
      .addService()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((response) => {
          if (response)
            return this.taskServices
              .clean()
              .pipe(tap(() => console.log('Done cleaning')));

          return of('nothing happened');
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```